# Cannot GET / in Angular2 and Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am modifying [this GitHub sample app](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter) to use Express instead of KOA.  The app launches when I type `gulp serve` in the CentOS 7 terminal, but when I type `http : // localhost : 8080` in the browser, a 404 error results with the message:

```
Cannot GET /
```

The only three changes I made to the code so far were to `server/index.js`, `router.js`, and `package.json`.  All changes so far are summarized as follows:

---

server/index.js

---

The new code to replace [`server/index.js`](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/server/index.js) is:

```
// set up ======================================================================
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;                // set the port
var morgan = require('morgan');             // log requests to the console (express4)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
var methodOverride = require('method-override'); // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));                 // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev'));                                         // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));            // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/'));

// load the routes
require('./router');

// listen (start app with node server.js) ======================================
app.listen(port);
console.log("App listening on port " + port);
```

---

router.js

---

And I added the following to the bottom of [`router.js`](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/server/router.js), but the console does not print the `inside / route` message, which means that the Express route is not being called:

```
router.get('*', function(req, res) {
    console.log('inside / route!');
    res.sendfile('./client/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the front-end)
});
```

---

package.json

---

The new `package.json` reflecting the new dependencies is:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-esnext-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/index.js",
    "test": "COVERAGE_ENABLED=true gulp test",
    "webdriver-update": "webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter.git"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "blacksonic",
    "email": "soos.gabor86@gmail.com"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "keywords": [
    "angular2",
    "es6",
    "webpack",
    "gulp"
  ],
  "description": "Angular 2 development in Javascript with ES6/ES7 syntax powered by Babel.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.4.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "jsonwebtoken": "7.0.1",
    "morgan": "^1.1.1",
    "method-override": "^2.1.3",

    "node-uuid": "1.4.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "babel-core": "6.10.4",
    "babel-eslint": "6.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-__coverage__": "11.0.0",
    "babel-preset-angular2": "0.0.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.9.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "codeclimate-test-reporter": "0.3.3",
    "del": "2.2.1",
    "es6-promise": "3.2.1",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-cssnano": "2.1.2",
    "gulp-delete-lines": "0.0.7",
    "gulp-eslint": "3.0.1",
    "gulp-less": "3.1.0",
    "gulp-nodemon": "2.1.0",
    "gulp-protractor": "2.4.0",
    "gulp-util": "3.0.7",
    "gulp-watch": "4.3.8",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "1.7.0",
    "localStorage": "1.0.3",
    "mini-lr": "0.1.9",
    "phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.7",
    "protractor": "3.3.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "run-sequence": "1.2.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "validate.js": "0.10.0",
    "webpack": "1.13.1",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  }
}
```

**What specific changes need to be made to the code to resolve this 404 error?**

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to actually use the router with the application:

```
app.use(router.routes());
```

After you require it.

Comment: I tried `var router = require('./router');  app.use(router.routes());`, but the browser just gets stuck in a holding pattern without returning anything.  No error.  No success.  Nothing.  Your suggestion is thus only part of the answer.  What else can I try?